# Incomplete last batch in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am quite new and could not find a direct answer to this question. I am wondering what is the default strategy that tensorflow 2.0 uses to deal with an incomplete last batch in training (eg. the 23 samples in a total training set of 1023 samples with batch size 100).

I am curious because intuitively if the same 23 samples are always being placed in the last batch of each epoch then these 23 samples would have a disproportionate influence (ie.1/23 each) on the gradient descent as compared to the other 1000 samples (ie. 1/100 each). I am wondering if the internal workings of tf automatically shuffles the samples every epoch.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two points regarding your question:

1. `tf.keras.model.fit()` has a keyword argument (kwarg) `shuffle`. It defaults to `True`. You can see the documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=stable#fit. The shuffling of the examples happens at the beginning of *every epoch*. Therefore, in each training epoch, which examples end up in the last batch is randomized. In this regard, no example gets special treatment or undue influence.
2. The loss- and metric-calculation mechanism of the `fit()` method takes into account the batch sizes internally. The final loss and metric values output by the method are *weighted* averages across batches, with the batch size being the weight.